# Auto-download an image stored in S3 on IOS (Iphone/Ipad) mobile browser

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, amazon-s3, browser

Hope you guys are doing fine.

We are developing a functionality where customers can click on the download button and download an image. Image is stored in S3 and a public URL is generated which is kept behind the button.

Something like

```
<a href="S3Url">Download</a>
```

Current exp:
When customer clicks on the download button

- For desktop - windows / IOS (Mac) - auto download is happening
- When we are trying on android mobile browser - auto-download is happening
- **When we are trying on IOS mobile browser (iPhone/Ipad), the file is just opening, no auto-download.**
- When we are trying on the mobile browser using a chrome toggle device on MAC(which technically acts as a mobile browser) - auto-download is happening.

So need assistance on

- Whether it's possible to auto-download the image in iPhone/Ipad browser using the S3 public link? If yes how can we achieve it?

Note:

- Code written is in JavaScript to trigger the download.

```
Sample:
var downloadElement = document.createElement('a');
downloadElement.href = S3Url;
downloadElement.click();
```

- Browsers tried are chrome, firefox, and safari. Experience is the same across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the `download` attribute to your links. This allows it work correctly for me using Safari.

Something like this, perhaps:

```
var downloadElement = document.createElement('a');
downloadElement.href = S3Url;
downloadElement.download = "filename.jpg";
downloadElement.click();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download